# Caliper benchmark online results are not generated

Tags: caliper

I followed the isnstructions in http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/OnlineResults?show=content and have a key generated for me. I put this key into the file ~/.caliperrc in my Linux machine and defined the account on Google. When I run my benchmark nothing happens there: on my page on http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com it is "No benchmarks yet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this should definitely work for you.  A few things to check:

- You included the whole line.  The "`apiKey:`" part is necessary.  So you should have a whole line that looks like: `apiKey: ffffffff-0000-0000-0000-ffffffffffff`
- It could be that there are connectivity issues.  You're not behind a proxy or something are you?  If you need to, you can specify the proxy as: `proxy: foo.com:8080`

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If you click the check to the left of the answer, that indicates that the question was answered.